# sql server 2008 Management Studio does not see my copied database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I copied my database (mdf and ldf files) from my server to the cloud.  Previously I have done it from one local server to another. I put it in the same directory (MSQLSERVER/../../data, confirmed that the path in SQLServer for the data is that.  But it does not show up in Management Studio. Is it to do with permissions or ownership etc or something else?

Only thing is this is on e: driver, and the master and tempdb databases are on an identical directory on c drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities, including file access permissions.

What seems to be more common in my experience is if you're trying to use the Attach Database wizard.  In the wizard, Sql Server Management Studio can only see drives that are local to the computer it is running from.  So, if you are using it to manage a remote server, you will not be able to attach pre-existing databases from files.

A couple ways around this are to remote desktop into the server and run it from there, or to use the CREATE DATABASE....FOR ATTACH command.